# Extend SO "Add Item" dialog to search on Alternate Item Description - Override DAC Projection

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to extend the SO "Add Item" (Item Lookup) dialog so that it searches on the Alternate Item Description, however, I can't seem to get the extension to the DAC Projection to take.  Here is the complete code of the SO Graph Extension:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using CRLocation = PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        public static bool IsActive() => true;
    }


[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[PXProjection(typeof(Select2<
    InventoryItem,
    LeftJoin<INSiteStatus,
        On<INSiteStatus.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
        And<InventoryItem.stkItem, Equal<boolTrue>,
        And<INSiteStatus.siteID, NotEqual<SiteAttribute.transitSiteID>>>>,
    LeftJoin<INSubItem,
        On<INSiteStatus.FK.SubItem>,
    LeftJoin<INSite,
        On2<INSiteStatus.FK.Site,
        And<INSite.baseCuryID, EqualBaseCuryID<Current2<SOOrder.branchID>>>>,
    LeftJoin<INItemXRef,
        On<INItemXRef.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
        And2<
            Where<INItemXRef.subItemID, Equal<INSiteStatus.subItemID>,
                Or<INSiteStatus.subItemID, IsNull>>,
            And<Where<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.barCode>, IsNotNull,
                And<INItemXRef.alternateType, Equal<INAlternateType.barcode>>>>>>,

    LeftJoin<INItemPartNumber,
        On<INItemPartNumber.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,

        // my change here, swapped alternateID to descr
        And<INItemPartNumber.descr, Like<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.inventory_Wildcard>>,

        And2<
            Where<INItemPartNumber.bAccountID, Equal<Zero>,
                Or<INItemPartNumber.bAccountID, Equal<CurrentValue<SOOrder.customerID>>,
                Or<INItemPartNumber.alternateType, Equal<INAlternateType.vPN>>>>,
            And<Where<INItemPartNumber.subItemID, Equal<INSiteStatus.subItemID>,
                Or<INSiteStatus.subItemID, IsNull>>>>>>,
    LeftJoin<INItemClass,
        On<InventoryItem.FK.ItemClass>,
    LeftJoin<INPriceClass,
        On<INPriceClass.priceClassID, Equal<InventoryItem.priceClassID>>,
    LeftJoin<InventoryItemCurySettings,
        On<InventoryItemCurySettings.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
        And<InventoryItemCurySettings.curyID, EqualBaseCuryID<Current2<SOOrder.branchID>>>>,
    LeftJoin<BAccountR,
        On<BAccountR.bAccountID, Equal<InventoryItemCurySettings.preferredVendorID>>,
    LeftJoin<INItemCustSalesStats,
        On<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.mode>, Equal<SOAddItemMode.byCustomer>,
        And<INItemCustSalesStats.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
        And<INItemCustSalesStats.subItemID, Equal<INSiteStatus.subItemID>,
        And<INItemCustSalesStats.siteID, Equal<INSiteStatus.siteID>,
        And<INItemCustSalesStats.bAccountID, Equal<CurrentValue<SOOrder.customerID>>,
        And<Where<INItemCustSalesStats.lastDate, GreaterEqual<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.historyDate>>,
            Or<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.dropShipSales>, Equal<True>,
            And<INItemCustSalesStats.dropShipLastDate, GreaterEqual<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.historyDate>>>>>>>>>>>,
    LeftJoin<INUnit,
        On<INUnit.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
        And<INUnit.unitType, Equal<INUnitType.inventoryItem>,
        And<INUnit.fromUnit, Equal<InventoryItem.salesUnit>,
        And<INUnit.toUnit, Equal<InventoryItem.baseUnit>>>>>
                            >>>>>>>>>>>,


    Where<CurrentValue<SOOrder.customerID>, IsNotNull,
        And2<CurrentMatch<InventoryItem, AccessInfo.userName>,
            And2<
                Where<INSiteStatus.siteID, IsNull,
                    Or<INSite.branchID, IsNotNull,
                    And2<CurrentMatch<INSite, AccessInfo.userName>,
                        And<
                        Where2<FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.interBranch>,
                            Or2<PX.Objects.Common.Bql.SameOrganizationBranch<INSite.branchID, Current<SOOrder.branchID>>,
                                Or<CurrentValue<SOOrder.behavior>, Equal<SOBehavior.qT>>>>>>>>,
                And2<
                    Where<INSiteStatus.subItemID, IsNull,
                        Or<CurrentMatch<INSubItem, AccessInfo.userName>>>,
                    And2<
                        Where<CurrentValue<INSiteStatusFilter.onlyAvailable>, Equal<boolFalse>,
                            Or<INSiteStatus.qtyAvail, Greater<CS.decimal0>>>,
                        And2<
                            Where<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.mode>, Equal<SOAddItemMode.bySite>,
                                Or<INItemCustSalesStats.lastQty, Greater<decimal0>,
                                Or<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.dropShipSales>, Equal<True>,
                                And<INItemCustSalesStats.dropShipLastQty, Greater<decimal0>>>>>,
                            And<InventoryItem.isTemplate, Equal<False>,
                            And<InventoryItem.itemStatus, NotIn3<
                 InventoryItemStatus.unknown,
                 InventoryItemStatus.inactive,
                 InventoryItemStatus.markedForDeletion,
                 InventoryItemStatus.noSales>>>>>>>>>>), Persistent = false)]
//[PXSubstitute(GraphType = typeof(SOOrderEntry))]
[PXSubstitute()]
public partial class SOSiteStatusSelectedCst : PX.Objects.SO.SOSiteStatusSelected //IBqlTable
{ }
}
```

For now, I've changed the code where the BQL query originally does the LIKE operator on `INItemPartNumber.alternateID` with `INItemPartNumber.descr`.

I've tried putting the class inside the `SOOrderEntry_Extension` as well as outside, and I've tried `[PXSubstitute()]` with and without `GraphType = typeof(SOOrderEntry)`.

I've ran SQL Server Profiler and have verified that the original query is still running -- the version where I switched `atlternateID` with `descr` still has `alternateID`.

I feel like I'm missing something simple.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to modify the projection.  Add the AlternateDescr field to the list of comma-seperated values, in the grid property 'FastFilterFields'.  This array of fields is used to specify which fields are used to filter the grid data.
[image]

Comment: That was my first thought too, so I've tried changing that property's value to "InventoryCD,Descr,AlternateID,AlternateDescr".   All that seems to do is turn on text highlighting in that field to show the pattern match -- it doesn't do anything to help the BQL query include more items in the resultset.

Comment: Chris -- that was part of the solution, but not all of it.  I had to put the code in an extension library (.dll).  Full code posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code of the extension.  Please note that I had to put this in an extension library (.dll) to get it to work.  It also needs the AlternateDescr field added to the fast filter fields as shown in Chris H's answer (and image repasted into this answer below).

Complete code:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using System;
using CRLocation = PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location;

namespace PX.Objects.SO.AI
{
    public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        public static bool IsActive() => true;
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [PXProjection(typeof(Select2<
        InventoryItem,
        LeftJoin<INSiteStatus,
            On<INSiteStatus.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
            And<InventoryItem.stkItem, Equal<boolTrue>,
            And<INSiteStatus.siteID, NotEqual<SiteAttribute.transitSiteID>>>>,
        LeftJoin<INSubItem,
            On<INSiteStatus.FK.SubItem>,
        LeftJoin<INSite,
            On2<INSiteStatus.FK.Site,
            And<INSite.baseCuryID, EqualBaseCuryID<Current2<SOOrder.branchID>>>>,
        LeftJoin<INItemXRef,
            On<INItemXRef.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
            And2<
                Where<INItemXRef.subItemID, Equal<INSiteStatus.subItemID>,
                    Or<INSiteStatus.subItemID, IsNull>>,
                And<Where<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.barCode>, IsNotNull,
                    And<INItemXRef.alternateType, Equal<INAlternateType.barcode>>>>>>,

        // original join 
        //LeftJoin<INItemPartNumber,
        //    On<INItemPartNumber.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
        //    And<INItemPartNumber.alternateID, Like<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.inventory_Wildcard>>,
        //    And2<
        //        Where<INItemPartNumber.bAccountID, Equal<Zero>,
        //            Or<INItemPartNumber.bAccountID, Equal<CurrentValue<SOOrder.customerID>>,
        //            Or<INItemPartNumber.alternateType, Equal<INAlternateType.vPN>>>>,
        //        And<Where<INItemPartNumber.subItemID, Equal<INSiteStatus.subItemID>,
        //            Or<INSiteStatus.subItemID, IsNull>>>>>>,

        // modified join
        LeftJoin<INItemPartNumber,
            On<INItemPartNumber.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
            And2<
                Where<INItemPartNumber.alternateID, Like<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.inventory_Wildcard>>,
                    Or<INItemPartNumber.descr, Like<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.inventory_Wildcard>>>>,
            And2<
                Where<INItemPartNumber.bAccountID, Equal<Zero>,
                    Or<INItemPartNumber.bAccountID, Equal<CurrentValue<SOOrder.customerID>>,
                    Or<INItemPartNumber.alternateType, Equal<INAlternateType.vPN>>>>,
                And<Where<INItemPartNumber.subItemID, Equal<INSiteStatus.subItemID>,
                    Or<INSiteStatus.subItemID, IsNull>>>>>>,



        LeftJoin<INItemClass,
            On<InventoryItem.FK.ItemClass>,
        LeftJoin<INPriceClass,
            On<INPriceClass.priceClassID, Equal<InventoryItem.priceClassID>>,
        LeftJoin<InventoryItemCurySettings,
            On<InventoryItemCurySettings.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
            And<InventoryItemCurySettings.curyID, EqualBaseCuryID<Current2<SOOrder.branchID>>>>,
        LeftJoin<BAccountR,
            On<BAccountR.bAccountID, Equal<InventoryItemCurySettings.preferredVendorID>>,
        LeftJoin<INItemCustSalesStats,
            On<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.mode>, Equal<SOAddItemMode.byCustomer>,
            And<INItemCustSalesStats.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
            And<INItemCustSalesStats.subItemID, Equal<INSiteStatus.subItemID>,
            And<INItemCustSalesStats.siteID, Equal<INSiteStatus.siteID>,
            And<INItemCustSalesStats.bAccountID, Equal<CurrentValue<SOOrder.customerID>>,
            And<Where<INItemCustSalesStats.lastDate, GreaterEqual<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.historyDate>>,
                Or<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.dropShipSales>, Equal<True>,
                And<INItemCustSalesStats.dropShipLastDate, GreaterEqual<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.historyDate>>>>>>>>>>>,
        LeftJoin<INUnit,
            On<INUnit.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
            And<INUnit.unitType, Equal<INUnitType.inventoryItem>,
            And<INUnit.fromUnit, Equal<InventoryItem.salesUnit>,
            And<INUnit.toUnit, Equal<InventoryItem.baseUnit>>>>>
                                >>>>>>>>>>>,
        Where<CurrentValue<SOOrder.customerID>, IsNotNull,
            And2<CurrentMatch<InventoryItem, AccessInfo.userName>,
                And2<
                    Where<INSiteStatus.siteID, IsNull,
                        Or<INSite.branchID, IsNotNull,
                        And2<CurrentMatch<INSite, AccessInfo.userName>,
                            And<
                            Where2<FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.interBranch>,
                                Or2<PX.Objects.Common.Bql.SameOrganizationBranch<INSite.branchID, Current<SOOrder.branchID>>,
                                    Or<CurrentValue<SOOrder.behavior>, Equal<SOBehavior.qT>>>>>>>>,
                    And2<
                        Where<INSiteStatus.subItemID, IsNull,
                            Or<CurrentMatch<INSubItem, AccessInfo.userName>>>,
                        And2<
                            Where<CurrentValue<INSiteStatusFilter.onlyAvailable>, Equal<boolFalse>,
                                Or<INSiteStatus.qtyAvail, Greater<CS.decimal0>>>,
                            And2<
                                Where<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.mode>, Equal<SOAddItemMode.bySite>,
                                    Or<INItemCustSalesStats.lastQty, Greater<decimal0>,
                                    Or<CurrentValue<SOSiteStatusFilter.dropShipSales>, Equal<True>,
                                    And<INItemCustSalesStats.dropShipLastQty, Greater<decimal0>>>>>,
                                And<InventoryItem.isTemplate, Equal<False>,
                                And<InventoryItem.itemStatus, NotIn3<
                     InventoryItemStatus.unknown,
                     InventoryItemStatus.inactive,
                     InventoryItemStatus.markedForDeletion,
                     InventoryItemStatus.noSales>>>>>>>>>>), Persistent = false)]
    [PXSubstitute(GraphType = typeof(SOOrderEntry))]
    public partial class SOSiteStatusSelectedCst : SOSiteStatusSelected  
    {

    }

}
```

The DAC extension above is used to alter the LEFT JOIN statement so that it searches on the alternate id's description.

And as Chris H specified, add the AlternateDescr field to the FastFilterFields.   This effects the SQL's WHERE statement.  The value for that property should now be `InventoryCD,Descr,AlternateID,AlternateDescr`

[image: Changing Fast Filter Fields]